# Using newsstand in regular application

Tags: ios, newsstand-kit

Can I use NewsStandKit in regular application ?
I need to use NKLibrary, NKIssue and NKAssetDownload classes in my regular application, do you think apple will pass that?

thanks

Comment: So you don't want it in the Newsstand itself?

Comment: yes, I want to use these classes only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use them unless you have your app be a Newsstand app. Apple will reject it.